# How to echo out the regex matching characters in sublime text?

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I am using regex find and replace in sublime text 2 to find these:

`[A-z]-[A-z`]

I want to replace them with

```
[whatever A thru z char came before dash]spaceCharacter[whatever A thru z char came after dash]
```

For instance,

```
input = D-f
```

should yield

```
output = D f
```

What is the syntax for this in sublime?

Comment: Some actual input and expected output would help. I think you want `([a-zA-Z])-([a-zA-Z])` as regex and `$1 $2` as replacement.

Comment: Be aware that `[A-z]` means `[A-Za-z\[\\\]^_\`]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Find**

```
(?i)[a-z]-[a-z]
```

**Replace**

```
$1 $2
```